# Correlation between rank and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

What can we say about a matrix which has the following property: $\det(A)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$? My guess is: if matrix A doesn't have a full rank that means that $\det(A)=0$ so that is not really an interesting case. If it does have full rank, that means $\det(A)\ne 0$ so it does mean that matrix A is regular but is there any theorem or some hint which I can come to a more concrete, stronger conclusion from than this? And is there a non-zero matrix which has some additional properties except $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\det(A)$?

Comment: $\det(A)\neq 0 \iff \text{rank}(A) = n$.  Beyond that, $\text{rank}(A)=n$ implies nothing beyond $\det(A)\neq 0$ and gives absolutely no further information as to the value of the determinant and $\det(A)=0$ gives absolutely no information as to the value of the rank beyond $\text{rank}(A)\neq n$

Comment: Thanks for input. Thats nice put summation of my post.

Comment: Comparing between these two quantities is not a very natural thing to do. In the context of real/complex matrices this isn't very manifest, but in general $rank$ maps a matrix to a natural number while $det$ maps a matrix to the field above which it is defined. So that the question even compiles is a coincidence of the fact that he most common example is above a field which contains the natural numbers.

Comment: So in this case we're looking at $n \times n$ matrices $A$ such that $\det(A)=n$.  AFAIK there's nothing particularly interesting about $n$ as a value of the determinant. Of course if $B$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, $\det(cB) = c^n \det(B)$, so if $\det(B) > 0$, or $\det(B) < 0$ and $n$ is odd, there will be a real $c$ such that $\det(cB)=n$.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Comment: Hmmm.  Well, it seems there are no $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\{0,1\}$ and determinant $n$ for $n = 2,3,4$, but there is for $n=5$, e.g $$ \left[ \begin {array}{ccccc} 1&1&0&0&1\\ 0&1&1&1&1
\\ 1&0&0&1&1\\ 1&0&1&0&1
\\ 1&1&1&1&0\end {array} \right] 
$$

Comment: Yeah obviously I meant when you are working over a field, in general $det$ is a map from $\mathcal{M}_k(R)$ to $R$ for any ring $R$.